# How do I grab a list of all fields in a content type?

Tags: nodes, entities

How would I grab a list of all the fields in a content type? Currently, I'm using entity_metadata_wrapper() to grab each field individually, but I feel that there's probably a more efficient way to get all of the values for a given content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [field_info_instances](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) to get a list of all fields for a specific entity / bundle.  In your case the entity would be 'node' and the bundle will be your content type.

Comment: This is correct. I just found it out myself shortly after asking.